# How to allow "click to pop-up"

Tags: configuration

A "click to pop-up" is a useful tool if properly used.  For instance to illustrate a text with an image, like a sized map or chart.  That's quite different to a pop-up on top or pop-up under. So, why Tor opens a "click to pop-up" in a tab?

Answer (score 2):

Popups are dangerous, whoever creates the popup gets to determine it's size, as such by making a popup with a very large size you can saturate the whole screen then use javascript to read back the screensize to determine the size of the users desktop.

As such, they're disabled. You can whitelist sites to be allowed use them from the popup blocking notification prompt but they'll open as new tabs, not as a new popup window.

For more information, see [#9881](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/9881) and [#12979](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/12979).